# How to understand Chi-squared goodness-of-fit for linear regression?

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I am trying to understand a claim from a paper*:

> The slopes were calculated using least-squares linear regression to fit the
> level versus X functions.
> The goodness of fit of these linear functions was then determined.
>
> ...
>
> C-levels decreased as a function of X in most
> cases. The rate of decrease was quantified by fitting a linear
> regression line to the level versus X functions.
>
> Chi-square Goodness of Fit values of
> the C-level versus X functions ranged from ~0 to 1 with a
> median of 0.06. All Chi-square values were smaller than 1,
> indicating good fit.

They had 3 levels of X with 3 measurements per level, and both X and C are continuous variables. **Edit:** There were 11 such independent data-sets, each coming from different subjects.

I am having trouble understanding what they are saying. Is this a standard procedure? There seem to be different “chi-squared tests”, but none of the ones I’ve found so far seem to fit to this kind of data.
I am mainly unsure about the claim that the fit is good if chi-square is below 1.

---

*NB: Neither me nor the authors of the papers are statisticians, so if the question is too simple, feel free to direct me to appropriate literature.

Comment: Could you explain how the authors appear to have obtained *multiple* "Goodness of Fit" values in this situation?  Your description makes it sound like there's a single dataset with nine observations; there should only be a single statistic and a single Chi-squares p-value for the regression.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. There were 11 such independent data-sets, each coming from different subjects. The fits and the chi-squared were then calculated separately for each of the datasets.